# Create VSFTPD accessible from public ip

Tags: vsftpd

For the past month I've been trying to setup this FTP server on my local machine (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) to be accessible from my public IP and have so far failed.

[My port forwarding setup in my router settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0fPY.png)

I've installed and configured `vsftpd` and have searched the web for instructions on how to do this, but all pages seem to only say how FTP sites within private networks but this is not what I'm looking for.

`vsftpd` is installed with the conf file [configured like so](https://pastebin.com/M3XkD7Xs).

My question is: Could anyone please list the things I would need to get this going, so that I can start a `vsftpd` that is accessible with a public IP?

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: what do you mean?